# unable to change opacity of jQuery image slider using css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm helping a friend with a website and we cannot change the opacity of an image slider that uses jQuery.

we have tried `opacity:1;` and `background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);`

http://cafe.cic.hull.ac.uk/~374332/IM_v2_New/HTML/index.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: please give more details, i cant understand what you need. opacity 1 normally is visible, 0 is invisible and between imagine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when [opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) on a parent container (the `#contentBorder` div in this case) is set to less than `1` any children inherit that and cannot be higher than the parent.

some alternatives:

1. create an alpha transparent background image to use on the parent so you get the same effect.
2. use [RGBA](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) or [HSLA](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsla-color) background colors on the parent (IE8 and lower not supported)
3. use opacity, but make the opacity on an empty sibling container that expands to the height/width of the content

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the child inherited, but my friend did, would have saved a lot of time and trouble if she said XD, thank you very much, all fixed now.